send_invoice в telebot вызывает HTTP 400 (Telegram Stars)
Моя попытка
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(
    text = 'Оплатить',
    pay  = True
))

bot.send_invoice(
    chat_id         = query.message.chat.id,
    title           = 'Подписка',
    description     = 'Покупка подписки',
    prices          = [LabeledPrice('Подписка', 50)],
    provider_token  = '',
    invoice_payload = 'subscription mo_1',
    currency        = 'XTR',
    reply_markup    = markup
)

Текст исключения
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\projects\python\LanceParseBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1215, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "d:\projects\python\LanceParseBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 150, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "d:\projects\python\LanceParseBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 93, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\projects\python\LanceParseBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 8707, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "LanceParse.py", line 350, in on_other
    bot.send_message(
  File "d:\projects\python\LanceParseBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1755, in send_message
    apihelper.send_message(
  File "d:\projects\python\LanceParseBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 273, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\projects\python\LanceParseBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 168, in _make_request
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\projects\python\LanceParseBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 195, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse entities: Unsupported start tag "telebot.types.labeledprice" at byte offset 172

Техническая информация

OS: Windows 10 Pro 22H2
Версия Python: 3.12.4
Версия модуля: pyTelegramBotAPI==4.21.0


у тебя в 'prices          = [LabeledPrice('Подписка', 50)],' выдает обьект класа telebot.types.labeledprice а нужны вроде бы float или int
оставь так
prices          = [50],
